# Problems installing python's library Polygon3 on MacBooks

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, polygon, python-venv

I have python version 3.11 and a MacBook M2 chip, and I'm having trouble installing Polygon in pycharm.

```
 pip install Polygon3 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
```

There's been an error.

```
        File "/Users/wangruizhi/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 278, in get_tag
          assert tag in supported_tags, "would build wheel with unsupported tag {}".format(tag)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp311', 'cp311', 'macosx_11_1_arm64')
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for polygon3
  Running setup.py clean for polygon3
Failed to build polygon3
ERROR: Could not build wheels for polygon3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've updated the version of the relevant library, but it still doesn't install properly.
Do I need to create a lower version of the python environment?

Comment: error may suggest that there is no version for `MacBook M2`